# Quicker internet access with provisioning restrictions

Tags: internet, performance, dsl

I'm currently working in a [place](http://www.multimap.com/maps/?zoom=15&countryCode=GB&qs=SO317ZN) where the max DSL speed we can get is 0.5Mpbs, I'm not sure exactly why, I think it has something to do with the private road that makes up the only access to the premises - apart from a river. (I don't think the owners don't like the road being dug up).

So, my question is this: what's the alternative?

1. Satellite - isn't going to be that
   much faster, plus the huge delay in
   transmission (and it's download only
   isn't it?)
2. Bind multiple DSL lines together?
3. Find somewhere to put a really powerful wireless connection!?

The business relies heavily on it's internet connection, and from what I understand they've only just moved here - so moving isn't an option!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your postcode/company telephone number (from the Multimap link provided and your website) you're serviced by the [Locks Heath BT exchange](http://www.samknows.com/broadband/exchange/STLOCKH) which appears to be ~3km as the crow flies from the location linked to. However due to physical routing you may find the actual line length is closer to 5-6km which is about the limit of an ADSL line.

I also did some sleuthing based on the address of your company and your neighbours on the same site as your premises (Universal Marina). Using Universal Marina's telephone number (also most likely supplied from the same BT DP) you may get up to 1Mb ADSL Max or 512kb fixed rate (1Mb fixed rate is reported as amber in the RAG info).

I suspect that the cable route back to the exchange will go via Sarisbury, Bridge Road and Park Gate which is why the line length is so long and hence the limited speed.

I doubt that local re-routing/replacement of the line would have any effect. I also doubt that if BT could dig a new route to a DP closer to the exchange it'd be economically viable. Judging by the aerial photo's there are lots of properties probably well serviced by existing infrastructure with existing wayleave agreements etc.

Your other options -

- Satellite - as you mentioned is going to have latency issues, but you can get services such as [tooway](http://www.tooway.com/index.html) (provided by Eutelsat) that provide two way access via satellite.
- Wireless - unless you have a local WiMAX/Mesh Radio provider in your area then you'd need to build your own infrastructure so that you have an ADSL service terminating in a building closer to the exchange, and beam the signal (via say microwave or other line of sight technology) back to your premises. This is expensive to do.
- Leased line type service (E1, Megastream) - may not be possible due to distance from the exchange, also it's in a whole different pricing world from ADSL....think £000's of pounds a year.
- 3G/mobile broadband - Three seem to have fairly good coverage where you are. For about £20 a month you can have up to 15GB data transfer and [speeds up to 3.6Mb](http://www.three.co.uk/Mobile_Broadband/Coverage_and_speed). You can also get one of these: [Huawei D100 Router](http://www.three.co.uk/Mobile_Broadband/Huawei_D100_Router) to allow you share the connection. I'm using one of these over in Donegal, Ireland out in the [boonies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boonies) where the service is rated at OK for outdoor use and it works just fine indoors.

But perhaps your best option is probably to investigate a [bonded ADSL service](http://www.aaisp.net.uk/kb-broadband-bonding.html) from company that specialises in this type of service.

Comment: Wow, thanks Kev. Great round-up, double up-votes if I could.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a couple options:

1. As you said, a wireless provider in your area could provide you with a very fast connection using line of sight and a small antenna in a clear location on the property.  This would depend solely on if there are any WISP in your area.
2. If the limitation is cabling on your property, but you could get a much faster connection delivered to a point at the edge of your property, then you could consider installing an exterior box/cube/hut/whatever at a point near the edge of the property and using your own point to point wireless to deliver the connection to the building.  Proxim makes a great two unit kit that I've used that makes the installation extremely simple.  We've used it to replace underground lines that have been cut by landscapers on our property with 2ms response times across long distances.

Satellite isn't going to be a very good solution because of the latency.  Cellular is another option but unless you're in a good 3G or higher coverage area, the speeds won't be much better than your DSL and you're going to have to deal with usage caps by the providers.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless can be a good option, there are several bands (Frequencies) you can get, some require FCC permits and some don't, and if there is a clear line of site that can effect which band you get.  Longer wavelengths can go through stuff like trees better.

Can you get T1 lines, cable modem?  I think you need to explain the restrictions a bit more.

Comment: The main restriction, as far as I understand, is the owners of the private road won't let BT/ cable companies to dig up the road to lay down better cables. I've no idea what's there currently, but we can only get 0.5Mbps.

Comment: Depending on the stay, it might be cheaper to go back to the private road and offer to pay to have a *better* road laid down for allowing you to did it up.  However, if they have buried the remains of their victims there you are probably out of luck.